# swagger with list of elements in an array

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am new to swagger implementation. I have a query parameter 'Geschaeftsvorfall' which can be of string value A or P and when I hit the end point. I expect an array[validPsd2Ids] filled with integers.

I have formulated below code and I don't know how to validate it. can someone tell me if I am going wrong some where? 
Also what can I do to print a List instead of array in my response?

```
    "parameters": {
      "Geschaeftsvorfall": {
      "name": "Geschaeftsvorfall",
      "in": "query",
      "description": "Geschaeftsvorfall",
      "required": true,
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "A",
        "P"

      ]
    }
  },
                  "definitions": {
                  "ValidePsd2Ids": {
                    "type": "array",
                      "items": {
                       "properties": {
                     "ValidePsd2Ids": {
                      "type": "integer",
                         example: [100000005,
                          100000006,
100000007,
100000008,
100000009,
100000010,
100000011,
100000012,
100000013,
100000014,
100000015,
100000016,
100000017,
100000018,
100000019,
100000020,
100000021,
100000022,
100000023,
100000024,
100000025,
100000034,
100000035,
100000036,
100000037,
100000038,
100000039,
100000048,
100000049,
100000050,
100000054,
100000055,
100000056,
100000057,
100000058,
100000117,
100000163,
100000165,
100000195,
100000196,
100000197,
100000198,
100000199,
100000201,
100000214,
100000217,
100000218]
              }
            }
          }

    }
    },

    "paths": {
    "/payments/validaccounttypes/": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "payments"
        ],
        "summary": "Valid PSD2 relevant accounts",
        "description": "Reads the list of valid PSD2 revelant IDs.",
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/parameters/Geschaeftsvorfall"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
               "items": {
            "properties": {
              "ValidePsd2Ids": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          },
              "properties": {
                "ValidePsd2Ids": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/ValidePsd2Ids"
                }
              }
            }

          }

            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: *"I don't know how to validate it."* You can use http://editor.swagger.io to check for syntax error. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Your parameter definition is correct. But the response definition does not look right. Could you please add an example of an actual response?

Comment: I have already verified the syntax using editor.swagger.io. I would like to know if its functionally correct. Do you mean the json response what I expect?

Comment: I expect the Json response like {"ValidePsd2Ids" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...]} like this.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter definition is correct.

The response definition is not correct. You say that the response looks like

```
{"ValidePsd2Ids" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...]}
```

In OpenAPI terms, this is a `type: object` with a property `ValidePsd2Ids` that contains an array of integers. This can be described as:

```json
  "definitions": {
    "ValidePsd2Ids": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "ValidePsd2Ids": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "example": [
            100000005,
            100000006,
            100000007
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

and the `responses` should be:

```json
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "OK",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/ValidePsd2Ids"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: if I want the same as a list.. should I change the type to List instead of array?

Comment: @TaiLung Sorry I'm not sure I follow. If you mean what if the response model is `type: array` directly without a wrapper property, this corresponds to an unwrapped array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.